Пропал счетчик строки слева в Pycharm
Слева от кода цифры, сколько строк содержит код.
Пропали цифры  в Pycharm у меня, как вернуть ?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Editor → General → Appearance Найдите опцию Show line numbers => поставьте галочку

Editor → General → Appearance
Найдите опцию Show line numbers => поставьте галочку
